# simplexml_load_file not working for some xml

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a basic common line to parse xml from file.
The issue is **XML 2** is parsing fine,but **XML 1** is returning NULL.
I have checked all errors ,look into everything,couldn't figure out yet.

Also tried with file_contents but still not working.

```
$xml =(simplexml_load_file($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA));
```

**XML 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msg:Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msg="urn:xmlns:SSE-HomeServices:Messages:Inbound">
  <msg:MessageHeader>
    <msg:senderOrgId>Actavo</msg:senderOrgId>
    <msg:senderTimeStamp>2017-12-06T09:16:57</msg:senderTimeStamp>
    <msg:contractId>CNR-420781-Z7L8Q8</msg:contractId>
  </msg:MessageHeader>
  <msg:Response>
    <msg:WorkOrders>
      <msg:WorkOrder>
        <msg:woNumber>W00521062</msg:woNumber>
        <msg:woNotes>Leak and aav all sorted .
Boiler now operating correctly and no leaks 
Sop7 done No combustion affected Visuals done </msg:woNotes>            
        <msg:isProductSwitchRequired>No</msg:isProductSwitchRequired>
        <msg:productSwitchReason xsi:nil="true" />            
      </msg:WorkOrder>
    </msg:WorkOrders>
  </msg:Response>
</msg:Message>
```

**XML 2**

```
<Message xmlns="urn:xmlns:SSE-HomeServices:Messages:Outbound" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MessageHeader>
    <senderOrgId>SSE</senderOrgId>
    <senderTimeStamp>2017-10-16T15:50:53.2291513+01:00</senderTimeStamp>
  </MessageHeader>
  <Request>
    <WorkOrders>
      <WorkOrder>
        <woNumber>W00617195</woNumber>
        <woCategory>Maintenance</woCategory>
        <woGroup>Gas Work</woGroup>
        <woType>Same Day Breakdown + Service</woType>
        <woInstruction>Cust has no CH or HW. Can an initial inspection be carried out too please. Please can we phone this customer asap due to previous lack of communication. Promotion :N/A Base Product Name :Boiler Cover Addon Product Name :Gas Service Feature Product
          Name :N/A Staff :False Landlord :False</woInstruction>
        <isCentralHeatingOperational>No</isCentralHeatingOperational>
        <isHotWaterOperational>No</isHotWaterOperational>
        <isCallOutChargeable>Non Chargeable</isCallOutChargeable>
        <isPartsChargeable>Determine on site</isPartsChargeable>
        <isLabourChargeable>Determine on site</isLabourChargeable>
        <dueDate>2017-10-17T14:49:00Z</dueDate>
        <name>Same Day Breakdown + Service workorder for Daniel Ward</name>
        <appointmentNumber>1</appointmentNumber>                    
      </WorkOrder>
    </WorkOrders>
  </Request>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for xml 1, you should add the namespace to [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) for `msg` like:

```
$xml =simplexml_load_file($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA, "urn:xmlns:SSE-HomeServices:Messages:Inbound");
```

You can also remove one set of parenthesis from your code.